# Level required for co-op mode in Spice Bandits

Tags: ios, spice-bandits

In [On5/Chillingo's Spice Bandits](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/spice-invaders/id467338170?ls=1&mt=8), what level, or what other unlock criteria do you need to be able to play co-op mode on levels?

I am level 17, but as yet have not been able to start a co-op mission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not when you complete all the single player. You get it just before the Italy level, I forgot which one exactly D:

Comment: You're right, it does unlock before the single player completes.  My wife unlocked it the other day so she might remember which level .

Answer (score 1):

You need to beat the single player game in order to play co-op.

Comment: The entire single player mode?  i.e. the whole world?

Comment: As far as I know, yes.

Comment: Cheers.  I'll confirm once I get to that stage

Answer (score 0):

Spice Invaders?   To earn co op, just start doing the Sudden Death and multiplayer vs's missions when you unlock them (as in, when you unlock new modes, go back to the first lvl and play the new modes on them) and eventually, you will hit a mission that has co op as the unlockable mode. You don't need to complete the whole game.